# What are the presets that can be used to emulate the rhodes through the Lounge Lizard vst?

Tags: sound-design

I am looking for ways to recreate the classic fender rhodes sound with Lizard Lounge. If there are better Kontakt libraries out there etc. I would love to know about these too.

- I am looking for the particular presets that emulate the keyboard
  that Herbie is playing here:
- The synth that comes in at 0:01 in this classic:
- Or the synth that comes in here at 0:02 :

Thank you for all your answers!